# How to subtract the "In stock" in a table when "Add Item" to another table

Tags: java, swing, jtable

In the right table below there are 3 cabbages:

[image: application screenshot]

After I "Add Item" to the table below, the "In stock" in the right table should change to 0, but it remains unchanged as shown in the picture. How can I fix this?

This is the code:

```
package com.mycompany.adremoveitemtoatablelist;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;

public class AnotherItemAgain extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    /**
     * Creates new form AddRemoveItemsToATableList
     */
    public AnotherItemAgain() {
        initComponents();
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel3 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        nameI = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jLabel4 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel5 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        priceI = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        quanI = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        addF = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        Item = new javax.swing.JTable();
        jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        showF = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jScrollPane2 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        Item2 = new javax.swing.JTable();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        addComponentListener(new java.awt.event.ComponentAdapter() {
            public void componentShown(java.awt.event.ComponentEvent evt) {
                formComponentShown(evt);
            }
        });

        jLabel1.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Segoe UI", 1, 30)); // NOI18N
        jLabel1.setText("Items");

        jLabel2.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Segoe UI", 0, 25)); // NOI18N
        jLabel2.setText("Item:");

        jLabel3.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Segoe UI", 0, 20)); // NOI18N
        jLabel3.setText("Name:");

        nameI.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Segoe UI", 0, 15)); // NOI18N
        nameI.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                nameIActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jLabel4.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Segoe UI", 0, 20)); // NOI18N
        jLabel4.setText("Price:");

        jLabel5.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Segoe UI", 0, 20)); // NOI18N
        jLabel5.setText("Quantity:");

        priceI.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Segoe UI", 0, 15)); // NOI18N
        priceI.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                priceIActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        quanI.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Segoe UI", 0, 15)); // NOI18N
        quanI.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                quanIActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        addF.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Segoe UI", 1, 15)); // NOI18N
        addF.setText("Add Item");
        addF.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                addFActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        Item.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Segoe UI", 0, 20)); // NOI18N
        Item.setModel(new javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel(
            new Object [][] {

            },
            new String [] {
                "Item", "Price", "In stock", "Type"
            }
        ));
        Item.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
            public void mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
                ItemMouseClicked(evt);
            }
        });
        jScrollPane1.setViewportView(Item);

        jButton1.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Segoe UI", 1, 15)); // NOI18N
        jButton1.setText("Delete Item");
        jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        showF.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Segoe UI", 1, 15)); // NOI18N
        showF.setText("Show Item");
        showF.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                showFActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        Item2.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Segoe UI", 0, 20)); // NOI18N
        Item2.setModel(new javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel(
            new Object [][] {

            },
            new String [] {
                "Item", "Price", "Quantity"
            }
        ));
        Item2.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
            public void mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
                Item2MouseClicked(evt);
            }
        });
        jScrollPane2.setViewportView(Item2);

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(183, 183, 183)
                        .addComponent(jLabel1))
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(66, 66, 66)
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                            .addComponent(jLabel3)
                            .addComponent(jLabel4)
                            .addComponent(jLabel5)
                            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addComponent(addF, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 152, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                .addGap(118, 118, 118)
                                .addComponent(jButton1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 177, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))))
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(45, 45, 45)
                        .addComponent(jLabel2)))
                .addGap(587, 587, 587))
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(223, 223, 223)
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                            .addComponent(nameI)
                            .addComponent(priceI)
                            .addComponent(quanI, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 224, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(29, 29, 29)
                        .addComponent(jScrollPane2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 535, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                        .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 535, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addGap(31, 31, 31))
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(189, 189, 189)
                        .addComponent(showF, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 176, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addComponent(jLabel1)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addComponent(jLabel2)
                                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                                .addComponent(jLabel3))
                            .addComponent(nameI, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                            .addComponent(priceI, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .addComponent(jLabel4))
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                            .addComponent(quanI, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .addComponent(jLabel5)))
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(230, 230, 230)
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                            .addComponent(addF)
                            .addComponent(jButton1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 37, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(30, 30, 30)
                        .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 270, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
                .addGap(48, 48, 48)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addComponent(showF)
                    .addComponent(jScrollPane2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 270, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addContainerGap(63, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void addFActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                     
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        
        if(nameI.getText().equals("")||priceI.getText().equals("")||quanI.getText().equals( "")){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Please enter all data!");
            } else {
               String data[] = {nameI.getText(),priceI.getText(),quanI.getText()};
               DefaultTableModel tblModel = (DefaultTableModel)Item2.getModel();
               
               tblModel.addRow(data);
               
               JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Add data successfully!");
               
               nameI.setText("");
               priceI.setText("");
               quanI.setText("");
        }
    }                                    

    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        DefaultTableModel tblModel = (DefaultTableModel) Item2.getModel();
        
        //delete row
        if(Item2.getSelectedRowCount()==1) {
            
            tblModel.removeRow(Item2.getSelectedRow());
        } else {
            if(Item2.getRowCount()==0) {
                
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Table is empty.");
            } else {
                
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Please select single row for delete.");
            }
        }
    }                                        

    private void ItemMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                  
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        DefaultTableModel tblModel = (DefaultTableModel)Item.getModel();
        
        // Set data to text field when row is selected
        String tblNameF = tblModel.getValueAt(Item.getSelectedRow(), 0).toString();
        String tblPriceF = tblModel.getValueAt(Item.getSelectedRow(), 1).toString();
        String tblQuanF = tblModel.getValueAt(Item.getSelectedRow(), 2).toString();
        
        //Set to text field
        nameI.setText(tblNameF);
        priceI.setText(tblPriceF);
        quanI.setText(tblQuanF);
    }                                 

    private void showFActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                      
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        
        String filePath = "C:\\Users\\ASUS\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\Food.txt";
        File file = new File(filePath);
                
                try {
                    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
                DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel)Item.getModel();
                Object[] tableLines = br.lines().toArray();
                for(int i = 0; i < tableLines.length; i++)
                {
                    String line = tableLines[i].toString().trim();
                    String[] dataRow = line.split(",");
                    model.addRow(dataRow);
                }
                
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
    }                                     

    private void quanIActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                      
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }                                     

    private void priceIActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                       
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }                                      

    private void nameIActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                      
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }                                     

    private void Item2MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                   
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }                                  

    private void formComponentShown(java.awt.event.ComponentEvent evt) {                                    
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        nameI.setEditable(false);
        priceI.setEditable(false);
    }                                   

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(AnotherItemAgain.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(AnotherItemAgain.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(AnotherItemAgain.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(AnotherItemAgain.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>
        //</editor-fold>
        //</editor-fold>
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new AnotherItemAgain().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JTable Item;
    private javax.swing.JTable Item2;
    private javax.swing.JButton addF;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel3;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel4;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel5;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane2;
    private javax.swing.JTextField nameI;
    private javax.swing.JTextField priceI;
    private javax.swing.JTextField quanI;
    private javax.swing.JButton showF;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

I want to subtract the number in "In Stock" in right table when "Add Item" to another table.

Answer (score 0):

There are several things I would change in your application however I will concentrate solely on how to achieve what you request, namely update the `Item` [JTable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) when the *Add Item* [`JButton`] is clicked.

You simply need to adjust the `TableModel` of `Item` and you should probably do it in the [ActionListener](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html) of the *Add Item* button.

Here is the code for method `addFActionPerformed`

```
private void addFActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    // TODO add your handling code here:

    if (nameI.getText().equals("") || priceI.getText().equals("") || quanI.getText().equals("")) {
        javax.swing.JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Please enter all data!");
    }
    else {
        String data[] = {nameI.getText(), priceI.getText(), quanI.getText()};
        DefaultTableModel tblModel = (DefaultTableModel) Item2.getModel();

        tblModel.addRow(data);

        javax.swing.JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Add data successfully!");

        nameI.setText("");
        priceI.setText("");
        quanI.setText("");
        int row = Item.getSelectedRow();
        int s = Integer.parseInt(Item.getValueAt(row, 2).toString());
        int q = Integer.parseInt(data[2]);
        Item.setValueAt(s - q, row, 2);
    }
}
```

The above code calculates the new value for *In stock* by subtracting the value entered in `quanI` [JTextField](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/text.html) from the current *In stock* value and sets the *In stock* value to the calculated value.

As an aside, some of the things I would change in your application are (in no particular order):

- Use a [ListSelectionListener](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/event/ListSelectionListener.html) rather than a `MouseListener`.
- Set the selection mode to [SINGLE_SELECTION](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/ListSelectionModel.html#SINGLE_SELECTION)

Also note that it is extremely rare that using the GUI builder of my IDE benefits me when writing a *Swing* application. In almost all cases, I don't use the GUI builder at all. I suggest that you do the same.

It is also a good idea to add validations to your code, for example to prevent entering a quantity (in `quanI`) which is greater than the *In stock* quantity.